# Move Windows Form Control in resize event

Tags: winforms

I have an application containing tab pages , on one of the tab page I have placed data grid view control. Now I would like to modify grid view location on the resize event of the tab page.Here is how my code looks like..

```
System.Drawing.Point pTabCntrlLocn= tabCntrl.Location;
System.Drawing.Point pDatGrdLocn = DataGrid.Location
int iCntrlYLocn = pDatGrdLocn .Y + 50;
DataGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(pDatGrdLocn .Location.X, iCntrlYLocn);
```

I not getting exception in last code line ,but also I cannot see control at new location nor the control location value modifies.

Please help me to track the missing link.

Comment: Dock property for that control is set to bottom and I am modifying the Y location of it.The control not at all moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Dock is set, changing the location will do nothing.

To change the size (in your case, the height), modify the `Height` property instead.